# Replace many text files by Sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm new in Sqlite. My application has million records saved in about thousand files. In order to save work to manage those files, I want to store those records in Sqlite. In my scenario, querying records isn't necessary but extracting all records inside a single file has to be very very fast. To prevent changing too much code, I want to simply map 1 file to 1 table. This means there will be thousand tables in Sqlite. Is there any performance impact or potential risk to create so many tables in Sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to save work by moving 1:1 file:table in sqlite. Access to the records could be faster than low-level io though, but you'll have to test with your specific situation.

In general you shouldn't really create multiple tables that have the same schema: just merge to one table and query that.

I think sqlite will handle 1000 tables just fine. I know it will handle a million records in a single table just fine. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to do a little test for loading time between multiple tables and one single table.